# Fit a GAMM with two fixed factors and their combination

Tags: time-series, interaction, generalized-additive-model

I would like to explore the effects of local climate zones (`lczs`), planting conditions (`pcs`) and their combination on leaf water content (`lwc`) and other water parameters. The `lwc` for 46 trees located in three different `lczs` (`CL, OL, SB`) under three different `pcs` (boxed, linear, unlimited) were measured 12 times between May and October, with in total of 552 (46 trees*12 times) measurements per tree. The model I built is:

```
model<-gamm(lwc ~ lcz + pc + lcz*pc+ s(time, by=lcz) + s(time,by=pc),random=list(trees=~1),dat=dat,method="ML")
```

I got the error:

```
Error in MEestimate(lmeSt, grps): Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

However, the model below works:

```
model<-gamm(lwc ~ lcz + pc + lcz*pc+ s(time),random=list(trees=~1),dat=dat,method="ML")
```

Does anyone know how to fix the error? And is it ok to use the second model (with one smooth term of 'time')? Many thanks in advance!

The data structure is shown below:
[image]

'time' indicates the day of year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is the problem, but you don't need `lcz + pc + lcz*pc` in the formula; you want `lcz * pc` *or* `lcz + pc + lcz:pc`.

What I think is the problem is the two smooths of `time` as there can be problems with concurvity and identifiability.

If `lcz` and `pc` and their combination define the fixed groups for which you want separate smooth curves, then you can do what you want with a single smooth of `time` as follows:

```r
dat <- transform(dat, lcz_pc = interaction(lcz, pc, drop = TRUE))
model <- gamm(lwc ~ lcz * pc + s(time, by = lcz_pc), data = dat, 
              random = list(trees = ~ 1), method = "ML")
```

That said, you may just be asking too much of the data or of GAMM. You might try:

```r
dat <- transform(dat, lcz_pc = interaction(lcz, pc, drop = TRUE))
model <- gam(lwc ~ lcz * pc + s(time, by = lcz_pc) + s(trees , bs = 're'),
             data = dat, method = "REML")
```

where we use the equivalence of smooths and random effects and encode the `tree` random intercepts as a `re` smooth. This won't be as efficient as `gamm()` for large numbers of random effects, but the `gam()` tends to be a more robust algorithm for fitting GAMMs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both models worked well! I also would like to consult you on another question. I have time series chlorophyll measurements (12) per tree and want to fit a gam to identify the periods with significant changes following the method you proposed in your paper. The model is: gamm1 <- gamm(chl ~ s(time), dat = data). I then tried to use: gamm2 <- gamm(chl ~ s(time), dat = data, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ time, p = 1)) to remove autocorrelation but ACF remains the same as the original model. The structure: corCAR1(form = ~ time) worked but the results were not satisfactory.